# While using writevalue in ObjectMapper for serialization using Jackson.It is flushing the underlying straem

Tags: jackson

Currently we are using Jackson to serialize.

And the problem is that I cannot write more than one map into the stream and my code is

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator.Feature.FLUSH_PASSED_TO_STREAM, false);
mapper.writeValue(writer, myMap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, setting `FLUSH_AFTER_WRITE_VALUE` to `false`, is what you are looking for.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-features#output-life-cycle-features